# How do I run a matrix regex or grep on the outer 'product' of two string vectors in R without a nested sapply?

Tags: r, sapply

Let's say I have a vector of strings, and a second vector of standard words that I'm interested in finding inside those strings. For example:

```
 a = c("aspirin 20mg", "ibuprofen 200mg", "diclofenac 50mg x 2", "phenobarbital 100mg")
 b = c("aspirin", "acetaminophen", "morphine", "ibuprofen", "warfarin")
```

I want to get back a `TRUE-FALSE` matrix of a regex of the `a` vector, looking for the standard substrings in the `b` vector. I would love if this was a matrix of `length(a) X length(b)`. What I naively thought would work is:

```
 outer(a, b, grepl)
```

I know that I could create a function that does a nested `sapply`, e.g.

```
 sapply(a, function(x) sapply(b, function(y) grepl(y,x)))
```

...but I feel like R should have something simpler that is related to the `outer` command. `mapply` feels stupid because I'd have to `rep` and wrap the outputs back into a matrix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure you need to nest your `sapply()` statements. Without nesting you can do:

```r
sapply(b, \(x) grepl(x, a))
#      aspirin acetaminophen morphine ibuprofen warfarin
# [1,]    TRUE         FALSE    FALSE     FALSE    FALSE
# [2,]   FALSE         FALSE    FALSE      TRUE    FALSE
# [3,]   FALSE         FALSE    FALSE     FALSE    FALSE
# [4,]   FALSE         FALSE    FALSE     FALSE    FALSE
```

Admittedly it is then a little cumbersome to add which string they match:

```r
sapply(b, \(x) grepl(x, a))  |>
    data.frame()  |>
    cbind(a)
#   aspirin acetaminophen morphine ibuprofen warfarin                   a
# 1    TRUE         FALSE    FALSE     FALSE    FALSE        aspirin 20mg
# 2   FALSE         FALSE    FALSE      TRUE    FALSE     ibuprofen 200mg
# 3   FALSE         FALSE    FALSE     FALSE    FALSE diclofenac 50mg x 2
# 4   FALSE         FALSE    FALSE     FALSE    FALSE phenobarbital 100mg
```

However, I like the idea of using `outer()`. You could combine that with `stringi::stri_count_fixed` and `setNames()`:

```r
outer(
    setNames(a, a),
    setNames(b,b), 
    stringi::stri_count_fixed
)
#                     aspirin acetaminophen morphine ibuprofen warfarin
# aspirin 20mg              1             0        0         0        0
# ibuprofen 200mg           0             0        0         1        0
# diclofenac 50mg x 2       0             0        0         0        0
# phenobarbital 100mg       0             0        0         0        0
```

Comment: I like the use of the `setNames` here... it fixes the problem with the other answer, even though the TRUE FALSE output is different. I think I need to combine both answers to make the exact output I was hoping for.

Comment: @quickreaction that sounds like a sensible approach

Answer (score 3):

To use `outer`, you need a function that takes vectorized inputs along both the input and the match pattern. `grepl` only accepts vectorized input, not vectorized patterns. However, `stringr::str_detect` does:

```r
outer(a, b, stringr::str_detect)
#>       [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]
#> [1,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#> [2,] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
#> [3,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#> [4,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Comment: I have a real aversion to using `stringr` because almost everything in it can be done in base R, but in this case that's not true and this is probably a slightly more appropriate function than `stringi::stri_count_fixed`.

Comment: @SamR agreed. I rarely use `stringr`, and always thought "when would I use vectorized pattern matching?" At least now this question reveals a good use-case.

Comment: Hopefully pushing the `setNames` function on `a` and `b` would also name the rows and columns. Good insights by both here